# SQL Server 2008R2 - WITH CTE AS disappears

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, common-table-expression

I have a table with owner names and some with multiple addresses.  I want to select only 1 address and it doesn't matter which one gets pulled as long as it is just 1.

I've created a view with the syntax below and have nested it in another view.

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT DISTINCT 
OwnerLesseeID, AddressID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY OwnerLesseeID
ORDER BY OwnerLesseeID) AS OL
FROM         OwnerLesseeAddress)
SELECT DISTINCT OwnerLesseeID, AddressID, OL
     FROM         CTE
     WHERE     OL = 1
```

It runs and executes as desired.  However, every time I save and close the view the WITH CTE AS ( disappears.  Whenever I re-open I have to insert in the part again to execute the query.

According to: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972(v=sql.105).aspx it is a temporary expression.

I don't think I can use MAX() because OwnerLesseeID is a UniqueID field.  Any ideas on how to mitigate this problem?

Comment: My first guess would be that your CREATE VIEW syntax might be wrong?      CREATE VIEW [dbo].[aview]  AS...

I'd double check that first.  Can you post your CREATE view script in its entirety?

Comment: I didn't use a create script.  Using Object Explorer, I right clicked on the view folder and used New View.  Wrote the syntax above and saved.

Comment: It could be that the GUI is doing something strange to cut off that portion of the view syntax.  I would give a manual script a try if possible-- I created a view populated by a CTE and the result was as expected.  See this link for an example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1579a/1/0

Comment: I tested that syntax using another GUID in my DB.  That works and saves as it should.  I added the row_number part to it and it seems that breaks the CTE.